# php mail multiple email with same emails

Tags: php, email

It is my code

```
$headers    = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: no-reply@domain.com\r\n";
$subject    = SITE_TITLE ." Account Upgrade Email!";
$to_email = user@gmail.com,user@gmail.com,user@gmail.com;

mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I sending mail to same email id three times....

three different emails will be sent or only one email will be sent....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it comma seprated, see `to` ref from [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
mail('user@abc.com,user@xyz.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I am clear about to but the matter i need to know in this mail function will send three different email or only one email...

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Comment: @DeepakKumar receiver will receive single mail, also in case of duplication in to

Comment: if it is like this mail('user@gmail.com,user@gmail.com,user@gmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers); what will happen..... same email address separated by comma.....

Comment: then also, user `user@gmail.com` will receive it single time

Comment: if you want to send multiple times, loop through!

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the email addresses.

This will send the same email to 3 different recipients

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: no-reply@domain.com\r\n";
$subject = SITE_TITLE ." Account Upgrade Email!";
$to_email = 'user1@gmail.com' . ', ';
$to_email .='user2@gmail.com' . ', ';
$to_email .='user3@gmail.com';

mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

See **[PHP Documentation on `mail` function (Example #4)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php/#example-3787)**